# sorting value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've searched but can't find a solution that works.

I have the following code - how can I ensure that the output is sorted alphabetically by $location["title"] ?

```
    <?php foreach($countries as $country): ?>
<option value="<?php $country["title"] ?>"><?php esc_html_e($country["title"]) ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Many thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but there must be dozens of questions on here about this already, I find it hard to believe you searched the site and didn't find them. If your situation is somehow different from every single example you found, you need to explain how, but it looks like a pretty simple case to me.

Comment: Thanks - I obviously didn't search hard enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
function compareByName($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}
usort($countries, 'compareByName');
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's great - it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: If my answer helped you please like it :)